# Where is physical location of apps in Android 12

Tags: android-12

Where is physical location of apps in Android 12?

I use x-plore as file manager to browse files. I look in both internal and SD storage but cannot find many apps. These same apps show on my phone and work.

For example I cannot find Amazon App anywhere in phone folders,

Comment: Apps are stored in `/data/apps` and their data in `/data/data` but on a non-rooted device you don't have full access to those locations.

Comment: you can't find any apps on any android version, they never existed on internal storage or SD

Comment: @Robert There is no apps folder under data

Comment: @alecxs So when app saves some mp3 files. Is there anyway to find them?

Comment: I see x-plore has a search function. Hopefully those mp3s are not saved internally in the App.

Comment: ah you're talking about media files. location has changed from /sdcard -> to /sdcard/Android/media/<pkgname>

Comment: @SNash there is an `app` or `apps` folder but you don't won't see it as neither apps not the adb user have the permission to list the files and folders inside `/data/`.

Comment: @Robert So you are saying if I Root my phone I will be able to see it?